# Evaluate expression on host machine and pass results to the provisioning shell script as an argument

Tags: vagrant

**What I've tried**

Vagrantfile:

```
...
config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, path: "provisioning/config-git.sh", args: "$(whoami)"
...
```

provisioning/config-git.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

username=$1

git config --global user.email "$username@stackoverflow.com"
git config --global user.name $username
```

After the machine is provisioned and I ssh into it here are the actual results:

**Actual Output**

```
# Host Machine:
$ whoami
axiopisty

# Guest Machine:
$ whoami
vagrant
$ git config --list
user.email=vagrant@stackoverflow.com
user.name=vagrant
```

Everything is working as expected except the argument that is passed to the config-git.sh script. The argument is `"$(whoami)"`. I would like to have the expression evaluated on the host machine so the username of the user executing the vagrant command is inserted as the argument to the script which executes on the guest machine as the vagrant user.

Assuming the username of the user on the host machine is "axiopisty" I would like the following results:

**Expected Output**

```
# Host Machine:
$ whoami
axiopisty

# Guest Machine:
$ whoami
vagrant
$ git config --list
user.email=axiopisty@stackoverflow.com
user.name=axiopisty
```

**Question**

How can I get vagrant to evaluate an expression on the host machine, and pass the results of that evaluation as an argument to the provisioning shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there but vagrant runs an SSH command with all parameters so your arguments are resolved within the guest VM. What you need to do is to save your username value from the host before making the shell provisioning passing as parameter this value.

Here is an example to be added in your Vagrantfile

```
  username = `whoami`.chomp # you need chomp as the result of the command executed this way returns \n at the end
  config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, path: "provisioning/config-git.sh", args: "#{username}"
```

The output of my local execution

```
fhenri@machine:~/project/examples/vagrant/ubuntu$ whoami
fhenri
fhenri@machine:~/project/examples/vagrant/ubuntu$ vagrant ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-29-virtual x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Last login: Wed Dec 16 22:59:01 2015 from 172.16.42.1
vagrant@ubuntu:~$ whoami
vagrant
vagrant@ubuntu:~$ git config --list
user.email=fhenri@stackoverflow.com
user.name=fhenri
```

Comment: Also, I just found out that, for this particular use case, I could use an environment variable as such: `config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, path: "provisioning/config-git.sh", args: "#{ENV['USER']}"`